# Using PersistentService to Access Files Within a JWS Codebase

Tags: java, file, directory, java-web-start

I have to write a program to be run by Java Web Start that will be a replacement to an applet that writes and reads files to local directories, amongst other things. I get the impression that I can use the `javax.jnlp.PersistenceService` class to access files within the directory structure of the codebase for my JWS program. My question is, can the PersistenceService methods retrieve a file from a subdirectory of that codebase directory structure? In other words, if the codebase is defined as `http:\\myServer.com\myApp`, could the PersistenceService access the contents of a folder `http:\\myServer.com\myApp\files`?

Comment: *"I get the impression that I can use the `javax.jnlp.PersistenceService` class to access files within the directory structure of the codebase for my JWS program."* You have the wrong impression. The persistence service only allows access to data that app. has explicitly stored into the persistence service. AFAIR they recommended using your own package structure to identify that data belongs to a particular app., but the data is not stored the same place as the downloaded resources. *"the contents of a folder.."* Note: A 'folder' is simply a GUI representation of a **'directory'**.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: is there a way for a JWS executable launched by a web app to share files with that web app and communicate with that web app? Based on what you say above, I'm holding out less hope for the former, but is the latter possible via muffins stored on the server?

Comment: A JWS based rich client can interact with a web service. If the web service is on the same server used to download the JWS app., it can even be sandboxed. But there is no inbuilt API that makes it simple.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks for your responses. After talking to my sysadmin, I think I'm going to use Java Web Start to launch a home-grown client-server solution...